# Run C# application without SQL Server Management Studio installed on client machine

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I have created a simple login application using the **C#.net**. I have some basic sql database(**I use SSMS**). There is name, email and password. I want my application to be usable from more devices (so I can't use localdb). *Everything works fine on my pc but when I move to another, where is not installed ssms it shows **error 26*** - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified.  I don't know how exactly to run my C# application without SQL Server Management Studio installed on client machine

I have researched for a weeks so I enable tcp/ip (from sql server manager), also add new inbound rules for tcp(1433) and udp(1434) ports in windows firewall. After that I allow remote connection and add sql server in windows firewall. Also I've tried to install SSMS on client machine but nothing

here are my conncetion strings

this one I tried to solve my problem 
Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxx;Integrated Security=SSPI

the other one is my main connection string
Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Integrated 
Integrated Security = True

The application works fine on my computer, I've installed Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server Management studio, but when I move to another computer it doesn't work.

Thanks to everyone in advance!!

Comment: The management Studio is not the issue. The SQL Server instance is not running on the machine. My guess is thus far you put in Localhost as the name/localtion of the server. That does not work if the Server is running on another machine.

Comment: Also note that meaningfully accessing a Server of any kind globally, is not trivial. It comes down to you paying enough to actually run a server reachable in the internet. Without paying, at tops you can get your application to share the same DB in the same network or via a VPN.

Comment: It actually because you use Integrated Security and it will authenticate you by OS Account. If you switch the computer you can't authenticate you by the OS Account of course.So create an account with username and password and write this Credentials to your connection string.

Comment: @lewa9 yea I've tried but no result. But thanks for your advice, I will try everything just to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

**SSMS** is just a **Database Management Tool**, the actual Database would by **SQLExpress** or similar. So on your remote host you need to install the latter and set it up correctly in you application to use to appropiate connectionstring to it.
`Schema compare` your tables from VS and your ready to go.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5528/installing-sql-server-2017-express/

Comment: Yea, I know. But I want to make my application work without installing any type of sql service on "client" machine

Comment: try SQLite, its headless :)

Comment: is it possible my mistake to be in connection string because I use windows authentication not sql server authenticcation with username and password

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to install sql or sql managemment studio in pc where you running your application, but just as your error said "Error Locating Server/Instance Specified", the server where you want to connect, is not accesible, thats means you should open your ports in pc where your sql server is hosted, and also, put your public ip following with that port in your server name in conectionstring, like Data Source=yourserver_IP:8076; tip: make sure your app pc and server pc are in same network.

Comment: I am not sure where exactly is my mistake because I have tried to enable tcp/ip (from sql server manager), also add new inbound rules for tcp(1433) and udp(1434) ports in windows firewall. I allow remote connection and add sql server in windows firewall.

Comment: is it possible my mistake to be in connection string because I use windows authentication not sql server authenticcation with username and password

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works on the same machine is most likely is is that when you go through another machine the connection has to go through a firewall that is blocking access to SQL Server. The default port that SQL Server uses is 1433 and unless you change it on the host machine when you connect from another machine that is the port that is use to connect and you don't have to specify the port. When you connect on the same machine that SQL Server is installed the firewall does not prevent you from connecting. Port 1433 is used for the default instance (The first installed instance on the machine).

Comment: Yea I add ports tcp(1433) and udp(1343) in firewall.

Comment: is it possible my mistake to be in connection string because I use windows authentication not sql server authenticcation with username and password